# Disable tail-log backup default

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Is there any way to globally set "take tail-log backup" to unchecked in MS Sql Server?
I would like to not have to switch to options and disable this option every time I restore a copy from backup.
TIA

Comment: Are you restoring over the existing database or as a new database?

Comment: Use T-SQL instead the SSMS GUI with the `REPLACE` option.

Comment: @J.D. This isn't a one time thing. Most often, I am restoring a backup to a new database, sometimes I might overwrite a test database with new data. The scenarios are different enough that scripts don't always work and I prefer to use the GUI. However, about the only thing that is constant is that I **DON'T NEED/WANT** to do a tail-log backup and have to click into the options page (which sometimes takes a while) just to unclick it every time.

Answer (score 1):

No the default can not be set. But whay you can do, is generate a script from the GUI and use that each time.

You can do that when going to restore the database and check the boxes you would like to be on or off.

Then press Script. This will generate the T-SQL script for you, which you can edit or if, everything, including locations are the same, reuse.

[image]

This will create the script:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The script option works well when I'm doing the same or similar thing. 
What I find myself doing if I want a copy of a database (usually to compare with an older backup because of end user error) is clicking on the database, going to task, picking the time I want to restore to and putting it into a new database. The only time I would want to take a tail-log backup is if I was overriding the production db, which I might have done once or twice in 20 years of working with SQL.

Comment: I understand the wish, haven't had the need neither in my years, perhaps you can make a feature request: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Peter, the problem, as I mentioned above, is that I have dozens of databases, backup files across several servers and the work involved in changing the filenames and locations in the script is way more than just clicking on the Options page and unchecking the tail-log.

The annoyance is that in my nearly 20 years of working with SSMS (as a developer, fwiw) I have NEVER needed to take a tail-log backup. But have to uncheck it 100% of the time.